# OpenCV .imshow() is not displaying a properly sized image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to read an image using opencv, do some transformations (resize and offsets), then as a last step, do a crop on the image. In my final line `crop_img = offset_image[0:1080, 0:1920].copy()`, I expect a cropped 1920x1080 image to be created. My crop_img.size print out shows that that is correct. But, when I do an .imshow(), it is displaying the full sized, original image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import copy

original = cv.imread("IMG_0015_guides.jpg", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_resize = cv.resize(original, (0,0), fx=.9, fy=.9) 


rows,cols,_ = img_resize.shape
M = np.float32([[1,0,100],[0,1,50]])
offset_image = cv.warpAffine(img_resize,M,(cols,rows))

crop_img = offset_image[0:1080, 0:1920].copy()

print('img_resize {}'.format(img_resize.shape))
print('offset_image {}'.format(offset_image.shape))
print('cropped {}'.format(crop_img.shape))

cv.imshow('image',crop_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

>>> img_resize (3110, 4666, 3)
>>> offset_image (3110, 4666, 3)
>>> cropped (1080, 1920, 3)
```

I'm totally baffled. Why is it not showing me the cropped 1920x1080 image?

Comment: You should probably add something to say what you were actually expecting to happen, this question is very unclear

Comment: @GPPK fair enough. Just reworked the question.

Comment: Just ran your code and it seems to work perfectly fine, are you sure it is showing the original image for you? try running imshow on both to check if you can see any difference between the two.

Comment: @Tom yeah it's definitely the original. It's a massive image, so it's very apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Working with massive images can get confusing when visualizing with OpenCV's imshow. 
I ran your code and it seems like its doing what you expect it to do. I suggest resizing your image again for visualization purposes only. The following code ran successfully on this [image](http://4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/4k-image-tiger-jumping.jpg).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import copy

original = cv.imread("4k-image-tiger-jumping.jpg", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# resize original for visualization purposes only
print('original {}'.format(original.shape))
original_resized = cv.resize(original, (0,0), fx=.1, fy=.1) 
cv.imshow('original_resize',original_resized)


img_resize = cv.resize(original, (0,0), fx=.9, fy=.9) 

rows,cols,_ = img_resize.shape
M = np.float32([[1,0,100],[0,1,50]])
offset_image = cv.warpAffine(img_resize,M,(cols,rows))

crop_img = offset_image[0:1080, 0:1920].copy()

print('img_resize {}'.format(img_resize.shape))
print('offset_image {}'.format(offset_image.shape))
print('cropped {}'.format(crop_img.shape))


# resize cropped for visualization purposes only
vis_r,vis_c,_ = original_resized.shape
cropped_resized = cv.resize(crop_img, (vis_c, vis_r))
cv.imshow('cropped_resized',cropped_resized)


# cv.imshow('image',crop_img)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```